# Make a high score when the score is higher than what the high score currently is?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an if statement that makes a high score when the score is higher than what the high score currently is. This is my code:

```
if scoreColorGame.score > scoreColorGame.highScore {
        scoreColorGame.score = scoreColorGame.highScore
        print(scoreColorGame.highScore)

    }
```

Whenever I run this `scoreColorGame.highScore` is always equal to 0. I have checked and the if statement is definitely running but this:

```
scoreColorGame.score = scoreColorGame.highScore
```

isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never change scoreColorGame.highScore.

Try this:

```
if scoreColorGame.score > scoreColorGame.highScore {
        scoreColorGame.highScore = scoreColorGame.score // SET NEW VALUE FOR scoreColorGame.highScore
        print(scoreColorGame.highScore)

    }
```